# How to remove a document inside an array in mongodb using $pull

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have the following document structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ffef283f1f06ff8524aa2c2"),
    "applicationName" : "TestApp",
    "pName" : "",
    "environments" : [],
    "stages" : [],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-01-15T09:51:35.546Z"),
    "workflows" : [ 
        [ 
            {
                "pName" : "Test1",
                "wName" : "TestApp_Test1",
                "agent" : ""
            }, 
            {
                "pName" : "Test2",
                "wName" : "TestApp_Test2",
                "agent" : ""
            }
        ], 
        [ 
            {
                "pName" : "Test1",
                "wName" : "TestApp_Test1",
                "agent" : ""
            }
        ]
    ],
    "updatedAt" : Date(-62135596800000)
}
```

I wish to remove the occurrences of

```
{
        "pName" : "Test1",
        "wName" : "TestApp_Test1",
        "agent" : ""
}
```

The resultant document should look like

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ffef283f1f06ff8524aa2c2"),
        "applicationName" : "TestApp",
        "pName" : "",
        "environments" : [],
        "stages" : [],
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-01-15T09:51:35.546Z"),
        "workflows" : [ 
            [ 
                {
                    "pName" : "Test2",
                    "wName" : "TestApp_Test2",
                    "agent" : ""
                }
            ]
        ],
        "updatedAt" : Date(-62135596800000)
    }
```

I've tried the below mongo query

```
db.getCollection('workflows').update({_id:ObjectId('5ffef283f1f06ff8524aa2c2')},
  {$pull:{workflows: { $elemMatch: {pipelineName: 'Test1'}}}} )
```

This is removing all the documents from workflows field including Test2 since Test1 is matched.

How can we remove only the entries for Test1 and keep the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the positional operator "$[]" :

```
db.getCollection('workflows').update({_id: ObjectId("5ffef283f1f06ff8524aa2c2")  }, {$pull: {"workflows.$[]":{pName:"Test1"  } }  } )
```

but the schema looks abit strange and after the update you will have empty arrays inside workflows if all elements got deleted in the sub-array.
To fix the empty sub-arrays you will need to perform second operation to remove them:

```
db.getCollection('workflows').update({_id: ObjectId("5ffef283f1f06ff8524aa2c2")  }, {$pull: {"workflows":[]  } }   )
```

Comment: Great, It leaves empty array elements. I completely missed positional operators.

Comment: Just tried it out and it works, awesome ! Had to run the second operation to remove the empty arrays like you mentioned. Yes the schema is a bit different but I can't change that.

Comment: Not sure if this can be achieved by single operation , maybe possible options are ordered bulkWrite or bundled in transaction ...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `$elemMatch` as it returns the first matching element in the array.

I am not sure there is another best way to do this with the provided schema design.

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zGoEN96mgPw)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$workflows"
},
{
  "$unwind": "$workflows"
},
{
  "$match": {
    "workflows.pName": {
      "$ne": "Test1"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    workflows: {
      $push: "$workflows"
    },
    applicationName: {
      "$first": "$applicationName"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    workflows: {
      $push: "$workflows"
    },
    applicationName: {
      "$first": "$applicationName"
    }
  }
})
```

1. `unwind` twice required to de-normalize the data
2. `match` to filter out the unnecessary doc
3. `group` twice required to bring the required output

You can save this to a collection using `$out` as last stage.