# MongoDB update operation not working using golang mongo-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mongo-go

This is with reference to

[How to remove a document inside an array in mongodb using $pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752420/how-to-remove-a-document-inside-an-array-in-mongodb-using-pull)

I need to remove empty sub arrays. I need to code this query in go lang

```
db.getCollection('workflows').update({<find condition>}, {$pull: {"workflows":[]  } }   )
```

So I've written the below code

```
nquery := bson.D {
    {"level", "application"},
    {"workflowName", workflowName},
    {"applicationName", applicationName},
}
nupdate := bson.M{"$pull": bson.M{"workflows":"[]"}}
UpdateOne(getContext(), nquery, nupdate)
```

The result of UpdateOne shows my query has matched but hasn't modified anything. So I'm guessing there is some problem with the nupdate. What am I doing wrong ?

The UpdateOne function is part of the mongo-driver for go lang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets "[]"  shall not be in quotes since now they are interpreted as string ... , they need to be added just as square brackets []  and require in golang: &[]int{} to be translated by the mongo goland driver to empty array ...

Comment: Tried nupdate := bson.M{"$pull": bson.M{"workflows":[] } } , it says syntax error: unexpected }, expecting type go. Sorry I'm new to go, so is this correct ?

Comment: nupdate := bson.M{"$pull": bson.M{"workflows": &[]int{} } } this worked ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`"[]"` is not an empty array in the query, it's a **string** having an opening and closing square brackets.

The MongoDB empty array can be "modeled" with an empty [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) in Go, e.g. with a value of type `[]interface{}`, so a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) of this type is `[]interface{}{}`.

So use this:

```
nupdate := bson.M{"$pull": bson.M{"workflows": []interface{}{}}}
```